# Display two table in two columns in a row on adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

I am using DropzoneJS and I want the template to be customized.

My template is as follows:

```
<div id="previewTemplate" style="display:none;">
    <table class="dz-preview">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-10">
                 <a href="#" class="dz-filename" data-dz-name=""></a>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
            X
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In dropzone.js, I have added a code as follows:

```
previewTemplate: $('#previewTemplate').html()
```

So, it is getting the inner HTML of the '#previewTemplate'.

I am getting all table in a single row.

Now, I want only two table in a row. That is, in each row I want two columns.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, when I wanted to put a table in a table I would specify a td tag or th tag inside the the td tag, then i'l put in two div tags that acts as the containers of the 2 tables and change their css properties to display "inline-block" or "table-td" and then i'l insert tables inside them, like this:

**CSS**

```
    .table_inner_1 {
    display: inline-block;
    }
    .table_inner_2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    }

/*this below is just to target both td's of both of the inner tables*/

    .table_inner_1 table tr td:not(:first-child), .table_inner_2 table  tr td:not(:first-child) 
    {
    padding-left: 5px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<div class="table_inner_1"><table><tr><td>dummy text</td><td>dummy text</td></tr>
</table></div><div class="table_inner_2"><table><tr><td>dummy text</td><td>dummy text</td></tr></table></div>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this works to put tables in tables if that is what you wanted.